# XPath expression to select all button or input type submit/button elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm writing a Python script that uses Selenium to select all clickable buttons by XPath.

I have these XPath expressions:

```xml
//button
//input[@type='submit']
//input[@type='button']
```

Is there a way to join these in a single XPath expression, to select only these types of elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the names and the attributes

```
//*[name()='button' or (name()='input' and (@type='submit' or @type='button'))]
```

or use the merge operator on three different queries

```
//button | //input[@type='submit'] | // input[@type='button']
```

Output should be the same, but the resulting order may be different.

Comment: The merge operator worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: If the first expression doesn't work, try replacing `name()` by `local-name()` in both occurrences. This should avoid namespace problems.